Soft 404 error in magento. How to force set the '404 page not found' redirection with 404 status code instead of 200
My website is done with magento Backend and react frontend. Hence the 404 redirection is happening with 200 status code for non existing urls. As we are using pure React, there is no way to set the statuscode to 404 using react. I have tried the below from server side. but its also giving a 200 redirection.
any other way to solve the soft 404 error of SEO
        $url = $request->getRequestUri();
        if($url == '/sample'){
            $this->httpResponse->setHttpResponseCode(404);
            $resultRedirect = $this->redirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('https://testsite.in/no-route/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

